# Change body background on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a transition like the below website using css, javascript or any other language. In short, except flash any language will do. The link is as follows  [www.graffdiamonds.com](http://www.graffdiamonds.com)

Comment: Please be more precise!

Comment: The example you give uses Flash, so it's not a very good example. There are sites like these that use HTML/JS, so have a look at those instead.

Answer (score 0):

in your css:

```
.elementToChange:hover{
 // style to apply on hover
 }
```